# How can I pass request body limit attribute value through appsettings/configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, middleware, kestrel-http-server

Kestrel only allows 30MB of request body in the POST request. I am changing the request body limit on a particular action method using [RequestSizeLimit(100000000)]

I would like to pass "100000000" value through configuration. Is there a way to do it?

Action

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestSizeLimit(100000000)]
public IActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel data)
{
}
```

This works fine but I am not able to pass it through configuration/appsettings

Comment: Attribute parameters have to be _compile-time_ constants.

Comment: @John Thank you John, Are you saying there is no way to do it?

Comment: I've found [this article](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-increase-file-upload-size-asp-net-core/) which shows how to set a limit based on a path, but I'm not sure how to do this at an action level.

Answer (score 1):

[RequestSizeLimit](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/RequestSizeLimitAttribute.cs) is an attribute that implements `IFilterFactory` and returns `RequestSizeLimitFilter` in `CreateInstance()` method. You can implement similar filter that will read this limit from configuration:

```
public class RequestSizeLimitFromConfigAttribute : Attribute, IFilterFactory
    {
        private string _configurationKey;

        public RequestSizeLimitFromConfigAttribute(string configurationKey)
        {
            _configurationKey = configurationKey;
        }

        public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var filter = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RequestSizeLimitFilter>();
            var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            filter.Bytes = config.GetValue<int>(_configurationKey);
            return filter;
        }
...
    }
```